# Crystal Formula to multiply Time by Cost

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a formula that would multiply {table.time} * {table.cost}. 
This is what I tried :
    tonumber ({@timeformat}) * {Table.cost}

```
Formula for {@timeformat}
whileprintingrecords;

numberVar hrs;
numberVar min;
stringVar hhmm;

hrs := Remainder(Truncate({table.time}/60),60);
min := Remainder({table.time},60);

hhmm := totext(hrs,"00") + ":" + totext(min,"00"); 


hhmm
```

When I simply do that I get a string error from Crystal when I run the report. 
String is non-numeric. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `{@timeformat}` is producing strings that look like `02:30`. They're useful for readability, but they're not numeric, nor can you multiply them.

Instead, try:

```
{table.time} * {table.cost}
```